# core-drawer-panel vs paper-fab z-index

Tags: z-index, polymer

I've got a fairly basic core-drawer-panel setup with a core-header-panel inside another core-header-panel in the main panel of core-drawer-panel. With me so far? OK.

Now in that container I have a paper-fab, which is great except it appears on top of the drawer when it slides out. I've tried messing about with z-indexes but can't seem to affect the drawer's z-index at all.

Anyone faced a similar issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Setting z-index of the drawer to big number solved it for me, without any side effects

```
core-header-panel[drawer] {
    z-index: 9999;      
}
```